# Read Excel file in Amazon Sage maker using R Notebook

Tags: r, file, amazon-sagemaker

I am having S3 bucket named "Temp-Bucket". Inside that I am having folder named "folder".
I want to read file named file1.xlsx. This file is present inside the S3 bucket(Temp-Bucket) under the folder (folder). How to read that file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the R Kernel on the SageMaker Notebook Instance you can do the following:

```
library("readxl")

system("aws s3 cp s3://Temp-Bucket/folder/file1.xlsx .", intern = TRUE)

my_data <- read_excel("file1.xlsx")
```